# Want to check if Java is installed and if so, which version

Tags: java, c#

I want to check in C# if JRE is installed, and secondly which version and if it meets the required version for my application.

I'm currently using the following code:

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey subKey = rk.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment");
string currentVersion = subKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
string neededVersion = "1.7";
if (currentVersion == neededVersion)
{
           //do something
}
else
{
           //do something else
}
```

But that only works on a computer with Java in it's Registry. Otherwise, you will get an System.NullReferenceException.

I have no idea how I should do this, could someone help me?

It is a bit difficult because I want to use two things asked earlier in one script.

Comment: Execute `java -version` in a CMD.

Comment: @Mahdad you can execute CMD commands in C# as well...

Comment: @Mahdad That is C#. You can run commands with System.Process.Start.

Comment: But if Java is not installed, there will be an error on `string currentVersion = subKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();` due to an System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: @AlbertJanPetersen If you look at my answer below, I've suggested a couple ways you can deal with that, namely try-catch blocks or null checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this, I think - one is the way you're doing this above, and the other would be as Luiggi suggests, which would be to execute a cmd command from your C# program.

I think you're probably better off just querying the registry like you're doing, but either using try-catch blocks or checking for null, and handling failure somehow.

However, if I'm mistaken, and there are common ways the user can have Java without having a registry entry, I would go with System.Diagnostics.Process. The System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo object can be used to construct all the options for the process and is passed to the Process before it is started.

```
try
{   
     ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(yourFilePath, yourArgument);
     procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
     procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

     Process proc = new Process();
     proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
     proc.Start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thats it! Using checks for null works great, however, I got a bunch of ifelse statements now.... But that's all right! It works fine, now!